# Motors would make the car go extreme left instead of forward (Self Driving car)

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, pwm, voltage-level

This is my very first day in the community, please bear me until I make myself comfortable here.
Coming to my question,
I'm making a self Driving car. 
My car instead of moving forward it moves on the left rigorously which makes the car go round and round.
Along with my arduino, I'm using the L298 bridge to control my motors.
The motors seem to work fine until put on the ground.
Can you guys help me with what could be the possible solution to this and make my car go forward.

```
Here's my code :



    const int EnableL= 5;
const int HighL = 6;  //Left side motors
const int LowL = 7;

const int EnableR= 10;
const int HighR = 8;  //Right side motors
const int LowR = 9; 



void setup() {
 pinMode(EnableL, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(HighL, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LowL, OUTPUT);

 pinMode(EnableR,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(HighR, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LowR, OUTPUT);

}

void Forward()
{
  digitalWrite(HighL,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LowL,LOW);
  analogWrite(EnableL, 255);

  digitalWrite(HighR,LOW);
  digitalWrite(LowR,HIGH);
  analogWrite(EnableR, 255);
}

void Backward()
{
  digitalWrite(HighL,LOW);
  digitalWrite(LowL,HIGH);
  analogWrite(EnableL, 255);

  digitalWrite(HighR,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LowR,LOW);
  analogWrite(EnableR, 255);
}

void loop() {
  Forward();

}
```

Components used :

3 pack lithium ion cells at 12V to power L298 bridge

A 9v cell to power Arduino Uno

Comment: what does this mean? ... `put on the ground` ...  placed on ground ...or ground wire connected

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/62889/l298n-motordriver